# How can I access the cliff sensors on an iRobot Create 2 via ROS/ Python?

Tags: sensors, ros, irobot-create, python

I have an iRobot Create 2 and am currently using the create_autonomy package. Currently, they have cliff sensors as a "planned" feature. I see in the documentation that there are 4 cliff sensors (which can return 0 (no cliff) and 1 (yes cliff)) and their "Packet ID" numbers.

It also mentions this note for each sensor: "NOTE: This packet is a binary version of the “Cliff Front Left Signal” (ID: 29) packet." I don't understand what this means or if it's relevant to what I'm doing.

How can I read this cliff sensor data (in order to publish a topic with it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to subscribe to the cliff state using ROS. The topic is /cliff_state, and it is of type Int16. Below is what I used in my code, where callback_cliff is my callback function.

rospy.Subscriber('/cliff_state', Int16, callback_cliff)

However, I'm still not sure what the packet ID numbers are.